# Statistical test for odds ratio when 1. N is large and not meaningful; 2. replicates are present

Tags: hypothesis-testing, odds-ratio, contingency-tables

I'm investigating the co-occurrence of 2 types of events (`var1` and `var2`). The hypothesis is that `var2` is more likely to occur when `var1` occurs. The data can be formatted into a contingency table as shown below. We have been describing this phenomenon using odds ratio (OR): `(D/B)/(C/A)`.

|  | Var1 = 0 | Var1 = 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Var2 = 0 | A | B |
| Var2 = 1 | C | D |

We would like to derive a p value for the alternative hypothesis that `OR != 1`. However, we couldn't directly use tests such as Fisher's exact test because:

- The data was generated using a high throughput method, such that the total amount of data points (N) **within each experiment** can be infinitely large (easily exceeding 100K). As N goes to infinity, even slight co-occurrence between var1 and 2 gave a very small p value.
- What we want to test is how reproducible this co-occurrence is **across different experiments**.

Therefore, I'm looking for a statistical test that does not rely on the N of each contingency table, but takes into account the different contingency tables from different experiments.

Regards.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What’s the problem with a large N leading to a small p-value? That’s how a test is supposed to work (related to a property called *consistency*).

Comment: What would this "statistical test" show you?

Comment: The goal is to test if the non-independence between var1 and var2 is reproducible across different experiments, each generating a contingency table.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly that means, but wouldn't a statistic like a standard error or margin of error suit that purpose?  Or perhaps you are looking for a prediction interval?

Comment: It seems that your problem is that with large amounts of data even small differences appear as significant, both within a single experiment and between experiments.  But it also should mean that estimates within a single experiment are more accurate, and similarly for the difference between experiments.  So you may want to reformulate your hypothesis to something like your $\frac{AD}{BC}$ ratios being between $0.99$ and $1.01$ in both experiments or whatever range is important to you